# ASP.NET MVC Authentication Redirect to Login Page with Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

In an asp.net mvc website, the site has enable forms authentication.

The form login page is located in an area such as:

Area: Area1, Controller: Account, Action: Login

When a user is not yet authenticated and click on a link that requires authentication, the user is redirected to the login page.  This does occur and redirect to the login page specify above.  However during debug, it was found the area value is not included in the RouteData.Values object.  That is, the RouteData.Values object has ONLY the follow value:

Controller: Account
Action: Login

*In this case*, it is presumed that the MVC application by default searches for the appropriate controller and action without consideration for including the area value.

On contrast when I direct click on a link that directs to login page, all processing occurs as expected, i.e. the area value is included in the RouteData.Values object.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the area value as follows:

```
 if (!RouteData.Values.ContainsKey ("area"))
    {
      if (RouteData.DataTokens["area"] != null)
      {
       RouteData.Values.Add ("area", RouteData.DataTokens["areaRegistered"]);
      }
      else
      {
       RouteData.Values.Add ("area", "");
      }
    }
```